# Ubuntu server grant existing user access to a new server

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu world. I am looking for different methods to be able to migrate/copy Ubuntu users from one server to another. From what I read about this it seems that LDAP will help with this, I am looking for an alternative. My predecessor has not been using LDAP and was able to move the users on to new servers, the documentation I have does not cover this.

My use case:

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 18.04 instance and already have about 30 other Ubuntu servers and about 15 users accessing some of them.

After I'm done setting up the new server, I want to migrate/copy some of those users over to the new server.

I would like to avoid creating a new user/new password for the same staff member on each new server, this would be unworkable.

I can adjust their folder permission and level of access as needed on each server, what I am looking for is for them to be able to SSH into the new server using their existing user/password/rsa public key.

Most of what I found so far on this was dealing with migrating users from an old server to a new one. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/

Thanks in advance for your help. 
LJ

Comment: In it's simplest form, copying `/etc/passwd`, `etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` over to the new server (and make the home dir availabe, e.g. via NFS) would work. 

However: This environment sounds like you **really** want LDAP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Moving forward I like to move to LDAP at the moment I lack the time for this, for now I am looking at an easy way around this. 

I tried to copy the user over, the issue I encountered was the user ID and the group ID are different for each user on each of the servers they have access to and I do not know if it is safe for me to just type in another user ID/group ID that is not in use in /etc/passwd and /etc/group.

Would copying the home folder contents over SCP work as opposed to using NFS?

Comment: Having different UIDs for a user on different servers is a nightmare. At the very least, you should make this the same on every machine. Until this is done, give the users on new servers UIDs/GIDs that are in use nowhere (e.g. just use 10000 as a base for uid numbering) and then slowly change the UIDs to the same value on every machine.

Comment: Sounds like a sensible approach, thanks for this. Can you advise how I can ensure they can login using the same password ? Would this happen be default as long as their home folder with the .ssh folder is moved over ?

Comment: For password based login, you need to make sure that the password hash in `/etc/shadow` is the same. If you use key-based login for SSH, then `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` matters and must include the key the user wants to login.

Comment: I think you solved my question (cannot see the check mark by your answers though). Will test and update.

Comment: I've just written comments, not an answer. I'll make this an answer later.

Comment: Tested your suggestion and they are working fine. If you post and answer I will mark is as a solution. Thanks again!